# XSL Translation for SOAP message

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have an XML message that I need to embed to a SOAP message. Basically, I have as an input, an XML message. I need to transform this using XSL to be a SOAP message.

Here's how my input XML message looks like:

```
<Transmission xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
    <TransmissionHeader>
        <Version>6.3.4</Version>
        <TransmissionCreateDt>
            <ExpressDate>20150916120546</ExpressDate>
            <TZId>Zulu</TZId>
            <TZOffset>+00:00</TZOffset>
        </TransmissionCreateDt>
        <TransactionCount>1</TransactionCount>
        <SenderTransmissionNo>355</SenderTransmissionNo>
        <ReferenceTransmissionNo>0</ReferenceTransmissionNo>
        <ExpressXMLElementName>ExpressShipment</ExpressXMLElementName>
        <NotifyInfo>
            <ContactGid>
                <Gid>
                    <DomainName>Express</DomainName>
                    <Xid>Contact1</Xid>
                </Gid>
            </ContactGid>
            <ExternalSystemGid>
                <Gid>
                    <DomainName>Express</DomainName>
                    <Xid>External1</Xid>
                </Gid>
            </ExternalSystemGid>
        </NotifyInfo>
    </TransmissionHeader>
    <TransmissionBody>
        <GLogXMLElement>
            <PlannedShipment xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
                <Shipment>
                    <ShipmentHeader>
                        <ShipmentGid>
                            <Gid>
                                <DomainName>Express</DomainName>
                                <Xid>28</Xid>
                            </Gid>
                        </ShipmentGid>
                    </ShipmentHeader>
                </Shipment>
            </PlannedShipment>
        </GLogXMLElement>
    </TransmissionBody>
</Transmission>
```

This needs to be transformed to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <SubmitXml xmlns="http://interface.bwlog.com/">
            <message>
                <Transmission xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
                    <TransmissionHeader>
                        <Version>6.3.4</Version>
                        <TransmissionCreateDt>
                            <ExpressDate>20150916120546</ExpressDate>
                            <TZId>Zulu</TZId>
                            <TZOffset>+00:00</TZOffset>
                        </TransmissionCreateDt>
                        <TransactionCount>1</TransactionCount>
                        <SenderTransmissionNo>355</SenderTransmissionNo>
                        <ReferenceTransmissionNo>0</ReferenceTransmissionNo>
                        <ExpressXMLElementName>ExpressShipment</ExpressXMLElementName>
                        <NotifyInfo>
                            <ContactGid>
                                <Gid>
                                    <DomainName>Express</DomainName>
                                    <Xid>Contact1</Xid>
                                </Gid>
                            </ContactGid>
                            <ExternalSystemGid>
                                <Gid>
                                    <DomainName>Express</DomainName>
                                    <Xid>External1</Xid>
                                </Gid>
                            </ExternalSystemGid>
                        </NotifyInfo>
                    </TransmissionHeader>
                    <TransmissionBody>
                        <GLogXMLElement>
                            <PlannedShipment xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
                                <Shipment>
                                    <ShipmentHeader>
                                        <ShipmentGid>
                                            <Gid>
                                                <DomainName>Express</DomainName>
                                                <Xid>28</Xid>
                                            </Gid>
                                        </ShipmentGid>
                                    </ShipmentHeader>
                                </Shipment>
                            </PlannedShipment>
                        </GLogXMLElement>
                    </TransmissionBody>
                </Transmission>
            </message>
            <referenceId>Express.28</referenceId>
        </SubmitXml>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I've already built my XSL like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SubmitXml xmlns="http://interface.bwlog.com/">
            <message>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/Transmission" />
            </message>
            <reference> 
                <xsl:value-of select="/Transmission/TransmissionBody/GLogXMLElement/PlannedShipment/Shipment/ShipmentHeader/ShipmentGid/Gid/DomainName" />
            </reference>
        </SubmitXml>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output I'm getting is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SubmitXml xmlns="http://interface.bwlog.com/">
  <message/>
  <reference/>
</SubmitXml>
```

Clearly I'm missing something on my XSL. Would be glad if you could point it out.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I've modified my post to rephrase my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes in your input XML are in a *namespace*. You need to declare this namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix, and use this prefix when addressing the nodes.

Here's a correction of your existing stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:otm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <SubmitXml xmlns="http://interface.bwlog.com/">
        <message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="otm:Transmission" />
        </message>
        <reference> 
            <xsl:value-of select="otm:Transmission/otm:TransmissionBody/otm:GLogXMLElement/otm:PlannedShipment/otm:Shipment/otm:ShipmentHeader/otm:ShipmentGid/otm:Gid/otm:DomainName" />
        </reference>
    </SubmitXml>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is not exactly the one you have posted, but that's for another question.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k! That was golden. The wrapping of the XML to a SOAP message will be my for own to resolve. Thanks again!

Comment: @LeoTagle Note that the reference is also not the same as the one required.